# For loop in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am trying to write a function which can print "Hello World" 50 times.

I am using Scala REPL and defining the function as below -

```
def f(n:Int) = for(a<-n) {if(n<=50) println("Hello World")}
```

However, I am getting below error -

```
<console>:11: error: value foreach is not a member of Int
```

Comment: While @jwvh already answered the question itself, I would like to point out the reason of the error and the rationale behind the solution. First, it is important to know that **Scala** doesn't have a  real `for loop` _perse_ - the `for` keyword is used as [syntactic sugar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html#example-1), and as you can see in the link's example, when it is not used together with the `yield` keyword, it is desugared as calls of the `foreach` method...

Comment: ...  Second, `n` is an **Int** and as such it does not have any _foreach_ method - thus that is why of the error message. The most common way to turn an **Int** into something which can be iterable is by using a [`Range`](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-range-class-in-scala-cookbook). `0 to n` means, create a Range _(which is a lazy collection)_ with all elements from 0 to n - it is equivalent to `List(0, 1, ..., n)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scala is functional language so we want to avoid mutation and be better to use recursive function instead of for loop.

```
 import scala.annotation.tailrec
  @tailrec
  final def printNthTime(str: String, n: Int): Unit = {
    if (n > 1) {
      println(str)
      printNthTime(str, n - 1)
    }
    else println(str)
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for (_ <- 1 to 50) println("hi")
```

Or, better yet.

```
print("hello\n"*50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to define a function and pass the loop iteration as an argument. You could use the below code to define the function and call it to run with an argument.

```
def f(n: Int) = { for (i <- 1 to n) { println("Hello World") } }

f(50)
```

Hope this helps you.